# How to filter array of string like rational numbers by regex in jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

There is an array:

```
numberList = ["2.1", "4.1.1", "3.0.1", "5.2.1", "7.0.1", "8.1", "5.0.2"]
```

I want to filter only those numbers which contain `.0` I have written a regex and checked it at [regex101](https://regex101.com) and it works there.

```
\d\.0(\..*)?
```

After that, I've written a `_.filter` function by underscore js and stored the filtered value into a new array named `filteredList`.

```
var filteredList = _.filter(numberList, function(num){ return num.search(\d\.0(\..*)?) });
```

So, the output should be:

```
filteredList  = ["3.0.1", "7.0.1", "5.0.2"]
```

But, I am getting error. What's wrong happened there?

```js
var numberList = ["2.1", "4.1.1", "3.0.1", "5.2.1", "7.0.1", "8.1", "5.0.2"];

var filteredList = _.filter(numberList, function(num){ return num.search(\d\.0(\..*)?) });

console.log(filteredList);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jashkenas/underscore/master/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
var numberList = [];
var options = $('#select_box');
$('#select_box option').each(function() {
    numberList.push($(this).text());
});

var re = /\d\.0/;
var filteredList = _.filter(numberList, function(num){ return re.test(num) });

console.log(filteredList);
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m2ne7tb8/3/)

Comment: Thanks! Can you please, give me a regex which accept first .0 only i.e it will accept 5.0, 5.0.1 but not 5.1.0?

Comment: You can try: `/^[1-9]\d*\.0(?:\..*)?$/`